# How to replace part of the text with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```html
<span class="price-measure">
    23,63 € / 1 m2
</span>
```

Now, I want to change "/ 1 m2" with "XYTEXT" but I don't know how.

I tried to use JS code below, but it's not working.

Thank you :-)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        var elem = $( '.price-measure span:contains("/ 1 m2 ")' );
        elem.text( elem.text().replace("/ 1 m2 ", "s DPH/m2") );
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<span>23,63 €</span>
<span class="price-measure">/ 1 m2</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        var elem = $('.price-measure');
        elem.html("s DPH/m2");
    });
</script>
```

Without changing the html content:

```
<span class="price-measure">
    23,63 € / 1 m2
</span>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        var text = $('.price-measure').text().replace("/ 1 m2", "s DPH/m2");
        $('.price-measure').text(text);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Than you but I can't change HTML content, don't have permission, I just can add <style> or <script> code to header or body.

Comment: @Patrik I added an option, without changing the html content, and using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector was wrong.  You were asking for a `span` inside of `.price-measure`, when what you really wanted was the elements `price-measure` that contained your text.

For good coding practices, I also moved your hard-coded values into variables so they didn't get duplicated.

(I also removed the extra space from the end of your search query to make things more robust.)

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var replace="/ 1 m2";
    var replaceWith  = "s DPH/m2";
    var elem = $('.price-measure:contains("' + replace + '")');

    // Make sure we have the element.
    console.log(elem);

    elem.text(elem.text().replace(replace, replaceWith));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="price-measure">
    23,63 € / 1 m2
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str1 = "23,63 € / 1 m2";
var str2 = "/ 1 m2";
if(str1.indexOf(str2) != -1){
     alert("23,63 € / 1 m2".slice(0,-(str1.indexOf(str2)))+ 'XYTEXT')
}
```

str2 is the selected text needs to be replaced. so I just remove that section from main string and concatenate a new string.

Comment: Please add an explanation.

Comment: str2 is the selected text needs to be replaced.  so I just remove that section from main string and concatenate a new string.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var price = document.getElementById('price-measure').innerHTML
document.getElementById('price-measure').innerHTML= price.replace('1 m2','s DPH/m2')
```

```html
i think good way use id with js not className 
<br/><br/><br/><br/>
<span id="price-measure">
23,63 € / 1 m2
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how do this using jQuery, but in pure JS, you can do:

```
const el = document.querySelector(/* your selector */)
el.innerText = el.innerText.replace("/ 1 m2 ", "s DPH/m2")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to pre-filter the elements, just iterate over them and replace their content:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var elements = $('.price-measure');
      
    elements.each(function(index, element) {
        element = $(element);    
        element.text(element.text().replace('/ 1 m2', 's DPH/m2'));
    });  
});
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="price-measure">
    23,63 € / 1 m2
</span>
```

If you have lots of elements and you need to pre-filter them before replacing their content, use jQuery's [**`.filter(...)`**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method to check, whether the specific element has the replaceable text:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var replacement = '/ 1 m2';  
    var elements = $('.price-measure').filter(function(index, element) {
        return $(element).text().indexOf(replacement) > -1;
    });
      
    elements.each(function(index, element) {
        element = $(element);    
        element.text(element.text().replace('/ 1 m2', 's DPH/m2'));
    });  
});
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="price-measure">
    23,63 € / 1 m2
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var t = $("span.price-measure").text().replace("/ 1 m2", "REPLACEMENT");

    $("span.price-measure").text(t);

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kr09pquz/10/

Answer (score 0):

You can try innerHTML property combined with split.

Something like this:

```js
var first_part = $('.price-measure').innerHTML.split("/")[0];
var second_part = $('.price-measure').innerHTML.split("/")[1];
$('.price-measure').innerHTML.split("/")[0].append('XYTEXT');
```